# Publishing on a wall as Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook provides a way of publishing on a wall as a Page:

Facebook.com->Account->Use facebook as page-> then click switch for desired page. After this whenever you publish on walls the page name will appear, instead of yours.

My problem is that I really don-t know how to do that via Facebook graph API.
  I am using restFB, and I am able to publish on whatever wall I want (based on Id), but only with the user already authorized with my Facebook application.

So the question is, how can I use graph API to publish on a wall as a Page? Similar to what Facebook provides in their GUI.

NOTE: Facebook let users who reads the wall to know if the message was published from a certain Facebook application, but this is not enough for me.

Any advice will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is from the Facebook dev site. Might help:
Page Login

You can impersonate pages administrated by your users by requesting the manage_pages permission.

Once a user has granted your application the "manage_pages" permission, the "accounts" connection will yield an additional access_token property for every page administrated by the current user. These access_tokens can be used to make calls on behalf of a page. The permissions granted by a user to your application will now also be applicable to their pages.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/